# Varnish with cookie-less domain - Same-Origin-Policy issue

Tags: javascript, varnish, same-origin-policy

If you use varnish it's recommended to use a cookie-less domain for external static files like JavaScript. If I do that I will have problems with the same-origin-policy. What's the solution for that?

Comment: Same-origin issues with javascript? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If want to use a separate domain for Javascript (I doubt about the recomendation in most cases), you will need to implement something like CORS [1].

This can be done at Varnish level (in your VCL), but the implementation won't be trivial (you have to code access rules by hand)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS